# Publishing a WCF Server and client and their endpoints

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, wcf

Imagine developing a WCF solution with two projects (WCF Service/ and web application as WCF Client). As long as I'm developing these two projects in visual studio and referencing service to client (Web Application) as server reference there is no problem. Visual studio automatically assign a port for WCF server and configure all needed configuration including Server And Client binging to something like this in server:

```
   <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultServiceBehavior"
    name="MYWCFProject.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MYWCFProject.IMyService">
     <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
     </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
     <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/MyService.svc" />
     </baseAddresses>
    </host>
   </service>
```

and in client:

```
<client>
   <endpoint address="http://localhost:8731/MyService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService"
    contract="MyWCFProject.IMyService"
    name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
    <identity>
     <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
   </endpoint>
  </client>
```

The problem is I want to frequently publish this two project in two different servers as my production servers and Service url will be "http://mywcfdomain/MyService.svc". I don't want to change config file every time I publish my server project. 
The question is: is there any feature in Visual Studio 2008 to automatically change the URLs or I have to define two different endpoints and I set them within my code (based on a parameter in my configuration for example Development/Published).

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer i [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210777/silverlight-application-cannot-accesss-wcf-services-on-other-machines/2210960#2210960) for a similar question (how to set client endpoints programmatically).

The other way to do it and keep it totally declarative is to write an installer for your app, and have the installer update the config files. This solution would be a bit more pure, but harder to implement, and exactly how it is done would depend on which installer you use.