# How do I avoid switching WCF endpoint when I deploy from localhost --> server?

Tags: wcf, web-services, endpoint

Right now I need to keep changing the line below. Is there a programmatic way to check if I am running the site locally vs. on production ?

The closest I got was this post but it seems to be referring to Silverlight and I am just calling from an asp.net site.

[Silverlight application cannot accesss WCF services on other machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210777/silverlight-application-cannot-accesss-wcf-services-on-other-machines/2210960#2210960)

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://www.punkoutersoftware.com/Service1.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
    contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

Comment: I ended up doing the really simple #DEBUG way... eventually Ill use web.config transformations.. almost the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very similar situation is covered here: [How to programmatically modify WCF app.config endpoint address setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966323/how-to-programatically-modify-wcf-app-config-endpoint-address-setting)

Answer (score 2):

Is this for an ASP.NET application?  If so, consider using VS2010's [Web.config Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx), which can alter your web.config based on your build type (Release, Debug, etc).

---

[Here's a better introductory tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/miscellaneous/article.php/c17407/ASPNET-Tutorial-WebConfig-Transformation.htm)